# Create ID column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a trading log. My problem is that I do not have any ID to match buy and sell of a stock. The stock could be traded many times and I would like to have an ID to match each finished trade.
My original dataframe a sequential timeseries dataframe with timestamps. The below example illustrates my problem, I need to match and ID traded stock in sequential order.
Very simplified example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'stock': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','C', 'A', 'A'],
                        'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell','sell', 'buy', 'sell']}) 
df1
Out[84]: 
  stock  deal
0     A   buy
1     B   buy
2     C   buy
3     A  sell
4     C  sell
5     A   buy
6     A  sell
```

Here is my desired output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'stock': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','C', 'A', 'A'],
                    'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell','sell', 'buy', 'sell'],
                    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1,3, 4, 4]}) 


df1
Out[82]: 
  stock  deal  ID
0     A   buy   1
1     B   buy   2
2     C   buy   3
3     A  sell   1
4     C  sell   3
5     A   buy   4
6     A  sell   4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without quantity, this is a futile goal.  For example, one can buy stock A today, buy more tomorrow, and then sell all of it on day three.  Or sell half the position before buying more again. Or one can open a position with a Sell short sale.

Comment: This is just a simplified example, the original df  contains what you mention. I have that covered. Good comment though!

Comment: Then you should probably base your identifier on when then cumulative quantity goes through zero.

Comment: Could you please add an example as an answer, not sure i Follow..be glad to upvote

Comment: I can add one a bit later.

Comment: Is the trading entity "Long Only", or can it enter into short positions?

Comment: Yes its , only long positions

Comment: @Alexander I have created a new question that more fairly describes what I would like to end up with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872407/pandas-calculate-trading-profit-from-dataframe-of-trades

Comment: Please refer to my solution in your linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
m = df1['deal'] == 'buy'
df1['ID'] = m.cumsum().where(m)
df1['ID'] = df1.groupby('stock')['ID'].ffill()

df1
```

Output:

```
  stock  deal   ID
0     A   buy  1.0
1     B   buy  2.0
2     C   buy  3.0
3     A  sell  1.0
4     C  sell  3.0
5     A   buy  4.0
6     A  sell  4.0
```

Details:

- Create a boolean series, True where deal equals 'buy'
- Cumsum and assign to 'ID' to buy records
- Use groupby and ffill to assign 'ID' to next 'sell' record buy
  'stock'

Comment: For Data df1 = pd.DataFrame({'stock': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','C', 'A', 'A'],
                    'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy','sell', 'sell', 'sell']}) , Output is: 
     stock deal  ID
0 A buy 1.0
1 B buy 2.0
2 C buy 3.0
3 A buy 4.0
4 C sell 3.0
5 A sell 4.0
6 A sell 4.0       which is wrong.

Comment: Yes, sorting the trades by transaction type doesn't work with this code, but if you sorted the trades by a timestamp them it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'stock': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','C', 'A', 'A'],
                'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell','sell', 'buy', 'sell']})

def sequential_buy_sell_id_generator(df1):

    column_length = len(df1["stock"])
    found = [0]*column_length
    id = [0]*column_length

    counter = 0

    for row_pointer_head in range(column_length):
        if df1["deal"][row_pointer_head]=="buy":
            id[row_pointer_head]= counter
            counter+=1
            found[row_pointer_head] = 1
            id[row_pointer_head]= counter

            for row_pointer_tail in range(row_pointer_head+1, column_length):

                if df1["stock"][row_pointer_head]== df1["stock"][row_pointer_tail] and df1["deal"][row_pointer_tail] =="sell" and found[row_pointer_tail] == 0:
                    found[row_pointer_tail] = 1
                    id[row_pointer_tail]= counter
                    break

    df1 = df1.assign(id = id) 
    return df1


print(sequential_buy_sell_id_generator(df1))
```

Output:

```
enter code here
    stock  deal  id
0     A   buy   1
1     B   buy   2
2     C   buy   3
3     A  sell   1
4     C  sell   3
5     A   buy   4
6     A  sell   4
```

Another Example:

```
For df1 = pd.DataFrame({'stock': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','C', 'A', 'A'],
                'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy','sell', 'sell', 'sell']})
  stock deal    ID
0   A   buy     1
1   B   buy     2
2   C   buy     3
3   A   buy     4
4   C   sell    3
5   A   sell    1
6   A   sell    4
```

Comment: Ah, very nice Mahir.

Comment: tried, and ended up with different results. For you last example the result is: print(sequential_buy_sell_id_generator(df1))
  stock  deal  id
0     A   buy   1
1     B   buy   2
2     C   buy   3
3     A   buy   4
4     C  sell   0
5     A  sell   0
6     A  sell   0 , the sell are all 0

Comment: There was an indentation error in the code after the second "if" clause, It happened while uploading the code in stackoverflow. Please check out the code now

Comment: Find out the code in this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IN1C9dOuNaLE7OTERYvmuH5uFcc75Zvk?usp=sharing