# Pandas calculate result dataframe from a dataframe of multiple trades at same timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, trading

I have a dataframe containing trades with duplicated timestamps and buy and sell orders divided over several rows. In my example the total order amount is the sum over the same timestamp for that particular stock. I have created a simplified dataframe to show how the data looks like.
I would like to end up with an dataframe with results from the trades and a trading ID for each trades.
All trades are long positions, ie buy and try to sell at a higher price.
The ID column for the desired output df2 is answered in this thread [Create ID column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865618/create-id-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/64866186?noredirect=1#comment114688808_64866186)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
     string_date =['2018-01-01 01:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
             '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
             '2018-02-01 12:00:00',
            ]



data ={'stock': ['A','A','A','A','B','A','A','A','C','C','C','B','B','B','C','C','C','B'],
                    'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy','buy','buy','sell','sell','sell','buy','buy','buy','sell','sell','sell','sell','sell','sell','buy'],
                    'amount':[1,2,3,4,10,8,1,1,3,2,5,2,2,6,3,3,4,5],
                    'price':[10,10,10,10,2,20,20,20,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =string_date)
df
Out[245]: 
                    stock  deal  amount  price
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       1     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       2     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       3     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       4     10
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       8     20
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       3      3
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       2      3
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       5      3
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       6      1
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       4      2
2018-02-01 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11
```

One desired output:

```
string_date2 =['2018-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
               '2018-01-02 12:00:00',
               ]

data2 ={'stock': ['A','B', 'A', 'C', 'B','C','B'],
                    'deal': ['buy', 'buy','sell','buy','sell','sell','buy'],
                    'amount':[10,10,10,10,10,10,5],
                    'price':[10,2,20,3,1,2,11],
                    'ID': ['1', '2','1','3','2','3','4']
                    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index =string_date2) 

df2
Out[226]: 
                    stock  deal  amount  price ID
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy      10     10  1
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2  2
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell      10     20  1
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy      10      3  3
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell      10      1  2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell      10      2  3
2018-01-02 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11  4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a typo in the `date time` index for rows with stock `C`. Hours should be the same instead of incrementing?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, I dont see it, could you be more specific? Are you refering to the different time stamps?

Comment: Please look at the rows with stock `C` in your initial dataframe. Indexes are `2018-01-01 04:00:00`, `2018-01-01 05:00:00` and `2018-01-01 06:00:00`. And in your expected output, you are doing a summation for these rows on `amount` column. Hence I asked, if this is a typo here. Because for other stocks `A` and `B`, indexes are same.

Comment: Thanks, I will change it and edit, one second.

Comment: @jonas please look at expected `df`. why last rec(2018-01-02 12:00:00 - `B`) with `ID` = 4? Looks like should be 2.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar, actually that is one of the tricky things , its a sequence and each buy and sell pair should ideally have the same id. So this is a new buy and hence given a new label, next sell in b with the same sum of the same amount will also be labeled B. Hope it make sence.

Comment: @Jonas Have you edited as per my question?

Comment: @MayankPorwal yes

Comment: @Jonas I've posted the answer. Please check and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes a 'Long Only' portfolio where short sales are not allowed.  Once a position is opened for a given stock, the transaction is assigned a new trade ID.  Increasing the position in that stock results in the same trade ID, as well as any sell transactions reducing the size of the position (including the final sale where the position quantity is reduced to zero).  A subsequent buy transaction in that same stock results in a new trade ID.

In order to maintain consistent trade identifiers with a growing log of transactions, I created a class `TradeTracker` to track and assign trade identifiers for each transaction.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframe.    
dates = [
    '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 01:01:00',
    '2018-01-01 01:02:00',
    '2018-01-01 01:03:00',
    '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 03:01:00',
    '2018-01-01 03:03:00',
    '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 04:01:00',
    '2018-01-01 04:02:00',
    '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 07:01:00',
    '2018-01-01 07:02:00',
    '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
    '2018-01-01 08:01:00',
    '2018-01-01 08:02:00',
    '2018-02-01 12:00:00',
    '2018-03-01 12:00:00',
]
data = {
    'stock': ['A','A','A','A','B','A','A','A','C','C','C','B','B','B','C','C','C','B','A'],
    'deal': ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'buy', 'buy', 'buy',
             'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'buy', 'buy'],
    'amount': [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 8, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3, 4, 5, 10],
    'price': [10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 20, 20, 20, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 11, 15]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))
>>> df
                    stock  deal  amount  price
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       1     10
2018-01-01 01:01:00     A   buy       2     10
2018-01-01 01:02:00     A   buy       3     10
2018-01-01 01:03:00     A   buy       4     10
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       8     20
2018-01-01 03:01:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 03:03:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       3      3
2018-01-01 04:01:00     C   buy       2      3
2018-01-01 04:02:00     C   buy       5      3
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:01:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:02:00     B  sell       6      1
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:01:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:02:00     C  sell       4      2
2018-02-01 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11
2018-03-01 12:00:00     A   buy      10     15

# Add `position` column representing the cumulative buys and sells for a given stock.
df['position'] = (
    df
    .assign(temp_amount=np.where(df['deal'].eq('buy'), df['amount'], -df['amount']))
    .groupby(['stock'])['temp_amount']
    .cumsum()
)

# Create a class to track trade identifiers and instantiate it.
class TradeTracker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.trade_counter = 0
        self.trade_ids = {}
    
    def get_trade_id(self, stock, position):
        if position == 0:
            trade_id = self.trade_ids.pop(stock)
        elif stock not in self.trade_ids:
            self.trade_counter += 1
            self.trade_ids[stock] = trade_id = self.trade_counter
        else:
            trade_id = self.trade_ids[stock]
        return trade_id

trade_tracker = TradeTracker()

# Add a `trade_id` column using our custom class in a list comprehension.
df['trade_id'] = [trade_tracker.get_trade_id(stock, position) 
                  for stock, position in df[['stock', 'position']].to_numpy()]

>>> df
                    stock  deal  amount  price  position  trade_id
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       1     10         1         1
2018-01-01 01:01:00     A   buy       2     10         3         1
2018-01-01 01:02:00     A   buy       3     10         6         1
2018-01-01 01:03:00     A   buy       4     10        10         1
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2        10         2
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       8     20         2         1
2018-01-01 03:01:00     A  sell       1     20         1         1
2018-01-01 03:03:00     A  sell       1     20         0         1
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       3      3         3         3
2018-01-01 04:01:00     C   buy       2      3         5         3
2018-01-01 04:02:00     C   buy       5      3        10         3
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1         8         2
2018-01-01 07:01:00     B  sell       2      1         6         2
2018-01-01 07:02:00     B  sell       6      1         0         2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2         7         3
2018-01-01 08:01:00     C  sell       3      2         4         3
2018-01-01 08:02:00     C  sell       4      2         0         3
2018-02-01 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11         5         4
2018-03-01 12:00:00     A   buy      10     15        10         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed your `string_date` to this:

```
In [2295]: string_date =['2018-01-01 01:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 01:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 03:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 04:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 07:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-01-01 08:00:00',
      ...:              '2018-02-01 12:00:00',
      ...:             ]
      ...:
```

So df now is:

```
In [2297]: df
Out[2297]: 
                    stock  deal  amount  price
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       1     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       2     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       3     10
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy       4     10
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       8     20
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell       1     20
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       3      3
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       2      3
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy       5      3
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       2      1
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell       6      1
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       3      2
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell       4      2
2018-02-01 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11
```

You can use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [2302]: x = df.reset_index().groupby(['index', 'stock', 'deal'], as_index=False).agg({'amount': 'sum', 'price': 'max'}).set_index('index')

In [2303]: m = x['deal'] == 'buy'

In [2305]: x['ID'] = m.cumsum().where(m)

In [2307]: x['ID'] = x.groupby('stock')['ID'].ffill()

In [2308]: x
Out[2308]: 
                     stock  deal  amount  price   ID
index                                              
2018-01-01 01:00:00     A   buy      10     10  1.0
2018-01-01 02:00:00     B   buy      10      2  2.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00     A  sell      10     20  1.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00     C   buy      10      3  3.0
2018-01-01 07:00:00     B  sell      10      1  2.0
2018-01-01 08:00:00     C  sell      10      2  3.0
2018-02-01 12:00:00     B   buy       5     11  4.0
```